# Wiki software for building public online tutorial

Tags: content-management-system, wiki

I'm building an online tutorial with a very simple layout: A tree navigation on the left and content on the right.

Eventually I would like to allow comments per each article (like blog comments) and allow privileged users to modify the tutorial contents. Maybe if the site becomes popular I will add translations in other languages.  Instead of reinventing the wheel I thought using wiki software would be ideal. I want something very simple where I have complete control over the CSS and markup.

Is there a wiki engine out there best suited to this? I was worried something like MediaWiki is too general purpose or overkill for my needs. There also seems to be a large overlap with CMS's and blog software for this type of thing I can't really determine the best what's best suited for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a WordPress plugin like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki-plugin/
Its simpler than mediawiki.

Comment: I gave this a shot. It's frustrating. I'm new to wordpress so I have a default install with the wiki plugin you mentioned.  The wiki "tree" menu by default only appears on the home page. It appears I have to modify the theme or install a different theme just to have the navigation tree appear on all pages.

Comment: I wound up using concrete5. Out of the box it got me close without installing any other plugins. Wordpress might have also - I just didn't spend much time with it.